# can fix that logistics problem about warehouse location problem vrp etc?

Tags: python

can help me solve that code

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "id": "0b33402e",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Set parameter Username\n",
      "Academic license - for non-commercial use only - expires 2024-04-24\n",
      "Gurobi Optimizer version 10.0.1 build v10.0.1rc0 (win64)\n",
      "\n",
      "CPU model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]\n",
      "Thread count: 6 physical cores, 12 logical processors, using up to 12 threads\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimize a model with 60 rows, 42 columns and 130 nonzeros\n",
      "Model fingerprint: 0x05b4d588\n",
      "Variable types: 12 continuous, 30 integer (6 binary)\n",
      "Coefficient statistics:\n",
      "  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+03]\n",
      "  Objective range  [1e+00, 4e+02]\n",
      "  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]\n",
      "  RHS range        [5e+01, 1e+03]\n",
      "Found heuristic solution: objective 205000.00000\n",
      "Presolve removed 39 rows and 25 columns\n",
      "Presolve time: 0.00s\n",
      "Presolved: 21 rows, 17 columns, 56 nonzeros\n",
      "Variable types: 0 continuous, 17 integer (5 binary)\n",
      "Found heuristic solution: objective 204797.00000\n",
      "\n",
      "Root relaxation: objective 1.268600e+05, 12 iterations, 0.00 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "\n",
      "    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work\n",
      " Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time\n",
      "\n",
    
      "\n",
      "Cutting planes:\n",
      "  Gomory: 1\n",
      "  Cover: 1\n",
      "  MIR: 3\n",
      "\n",
      "Explored 1 nodes (15 simplex iterations) in 0.07 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "Thread count was 12 (of 12 available processors)\n",
      "\n",
      "Solution count 9: 153300 154700 155900 ... 205000\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)\n",
      "Best objective 1.533000000000e+05, best bound 1.533000000000e+05, gap 0.0000%\n",
      "lotsize[0,0]: 900.0\n",
      "lotsize[0,1]: 800.0\n",
      "lotsize[1,0]: 0.0\n",
      "lotsize[1,1]: 0.0\n",
      "lotsize[2,0]: 0.0\n",
      "lotsize[2,1]: 0.0\n",
      "lotsize[3,0]: 500.0\n",
      "lotsize[3,1]: 800.0\n",
      "lotsize[4,0]: -0.0\n",
      "lotsize[4,1]: 0.0\n",
      "lotsize[5,0]: 1000.0\n",
      "lotsize[5,1]: 800.0\n",
      "orders[0,0]: 300.0\n",
      "orders[0,1]: 200.0\n",
      "orders[1,0]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[1,1]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[2,0]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[2,1]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[3,0]: 300.0\n",
      "orders[3,1]: 200.0\n",
      "orders[4,0]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[4,1]: 0.0\n",
      "orders[5,0]: 300.0\n",
      "orders[5,1]: 200.0\n",
      "Objective: 153300.0\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "#1\n",
    "import gurobipy as gp\n",
    "from gurobipy import GRB, quicksum\n",
    "\n",
    "# Input data\n",
    "demands = [[750, 100, 50, 100, 400, 1000], [500, 200, 100, 300, 500, 800]] # demand of two items\n",
    "setup_cost = 400\n",
    "holding_cost = [2, 1] # holding cost of two items\n",
    "order_cost = 100 # cost per order\n",
    "order_quantities = [300, 200] # order quantities for two items\n",
    "\n",
    "num_periods = len(demands[0])\n",
    "num_items = len(demands)\n",
    "model = gp.Model(\"Joint Replenishment\")\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create variables\n",
    "lotsize = model.addVars(num_periods, num_items, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=\"lotsize\")\n",
    "setup = model.addVars(num_periods, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=\"setup\")\n",
    "inventories = model.addVars(num_periods, num_items, name=\"inventories\")\n",
    "orders = model.addVars(num_periods, num_items, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=\"orders\")\n",
    "\n",
    "# Set objective\n",
    "model.setObjective(quicksum(setup[period]*setup_cost+quicksum(holding_cost[item]*inventories[period,item]\n",
    "                            for item in range(num_items))+quicksum(order_cost*orders[period,item]\n",
    "                            for item in range(num_items)) for period in range(num_periods)), GRB.MINIMIZE)\n",
    "\n",
    "# Inventory balance constraints\n",
    "model.addConstrs(inventories[0,item] == lotsize[0,item]-demands[item][0] for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "model.addConstrs(inventories[period,item] == lotsize[period,item]-demands[item][period]+inventories[period-1,item]\n",
    "                 for period in range(1, num_periods) for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "model.addConstrs(lotsize[period,item] <= 1000*setup[period] for period in range(num_periods) for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "model.addConstrs(lotsize[period,item] >= orders[period,item] for period in range(num_periods) for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "model.addConstrs(orders[period,item] <= 1000*setup[period] for period in range(num_periods) for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "model.addConstrs(orders[period,item] == order_quantities[item]*setup[period] for period in range(num_periods) for item in range(num_items))\n",
    "\n",
    "# Run model\n",
    "model.optimize()\n",
    "\n",
    "# Print results\n",
    "for variable in model.getVars():\n",
    "    if variable.varName.startswith(\"lotsize\"):\n",
    "        print(variable.varName+\": \"+str(variable.x))\n",
    "    elif variable.varName.startswith(\"orders\"):\n",
    "        print(variable.varName+\": \"+str(variable.x))\n",
    "print(\"Objective: \"+str(model.objVal))\n"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 2,
   "id": "66fa8223",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Gurobi Optimizer version 10.0.1 build v10.0.1rc0 (win64)\n",
      "\n",
      "CPU model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]\n",
      "Thread count: 6 physical cores, 12 logical processors, using up to 12 threads\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimize a model with 24 rows, 36 columns and 59 nonzeros\n",
      "Model fingerprint: 0xd4dc939a\n",
      "Variable types: 0 continuous, 36 integer (12 binary)\n",
      "Coefficient statistics:\n",
      "  Matrix range     [1e+00, 7e+02]\n",
      "  Objective range  [2e+00, 5e+02]\n",
      "  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]\n",
      "  RHS range        [4e+01, 1e+02]\n",
      "Found heuristic solution: objective 5400.0000000\n",
      "Presolve removed 3 rows and 4 columns\n",
      "Presolve time: 0.00s\n",
      "Presolved: 21 rows, 32 columns, 52 nonzeros\n",
      "Variable types: 0 continuous, 32 integer (11 binary)\n",
      "\n",
      "Root relaxation: objective 1.565549e+03, 13 iterations, 0.00 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "\n",
      "    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work\n",
      " Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time\n",
      "\n",
    
      "\n",
      "Cutting planes:\n",
      "  Gomory: 1\n",
      "  Implied bound: 15\n",
      "  MIR: 2\n",
      "  Flow cover: 3\n",
      "  Flow path: 6\n",
      "\n",
      "Explored 1 nodes (32 simplex iterations) in 0.08 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "Thread count was 12 (of 12 available processors)\n",
      "\n",
      "Solution count 7: 3452 3516 3806 ... 5400\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)\n",
      "Best objective 3.452000000000e+03, best bound 3.452000000000e+03, gap 0.0000%\n",
      "Objective: 3452.0\n",
      "Period 0: setup = 1.0, lotsize = 154.0, inventory = 108.0\n",
      "Period 1: setup = -0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = 0.0\n",
      "Period 2: setup = 1.0, lotsize = 186.0, inventory = 99.0\n",
      "Period 3: setup = -0.0, lotsize = 0.0, inventory = 35.0\n",
      "Period 4: setup = -0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = -0.0\n",
      "Period 5: setup = 1.0, lotsize = 254.0, inventory = 106.0\n",
      "Period 6: setup = 0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = -0.0\n",
      "Period 7: setup = 1.0, lotsize = 205.0, inventory = 114.0\n",
      "Period 8: setup = -0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = 61.0\n",
      "Period 9: setup = -0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = -0.0\n",
      "Period 10: setup = 1.0, lotsize = 176.0, inventory = 78.0\n",
      "Period 11: setup = -0.0, lotsize = -0.0, inventory = 0.0\n",
      "Cost: 4396.79264257376\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "#2\n",
    "import gurobipy as gp\n",
    "from gurobipy import GRB, quicksum\n",
    "# Input data\n",
    "periods = 12\n",
    "realised_demands = [66, 78, 57, 34, 5, 118, 76, 61, 23, 31, 68, 48]\n",
    "initial_forecast = 50\n",
    "alpha = 0.3\n",
    "setup_cost = 450\n",
    "holding_cost = 2\n",
    "backorder_cost = 20\n",
    "safety_stock = 30\n",
    "\n",
    "BIG_M = sum(realised_demands[t] for t in range(periods))\n",
    "\n",
    "model = gp.Model(\"Prophet\")\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create variables\n",
    "lotsize = model.addVars(periods, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=\"lotsize\")\n",
    "inventory = model.addVars(periods, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name=\"inventory\")\n",
    "setup = model.addVars(periods, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name=\"setup\")\n",
    "# Set objective\n",
    "model.setObjective(\n",
    "      quicksum(setup[t] * setup_cost for t in range(periods))\n",
    "      + quicksum(inventory[t] * holding_cost for t in range(periods)),\n",
    "      sense=GRB.MINIMIZE,\n",
    "   )\n",
    "# Add constraints\n",
    "# Inventory balance\n",
    "model.addConstr(inventory[0] == initial_forecast + lotsize[0] - realised_demands[0] - safety_stock)\n",
    "model.addConstrs(\n",
    "      inventory[t - 1] + lotsize[t] - realised_demands[t] == inventory[t] + safety_stock\n",
    "      for t in range(1, periods)\n",
    "   )\n",
    "# Logic constraints\n",
    "model.addConstrs(\n",
    "      lotsize[t] <= BIG_M * setup[t] for t in range(periods)\n",
    "   )\n",
    "# Solve\n",
    "model.optimize()\n",
    "\n",
    "# Print results\n",
    "print(\"Objective: {}\".format(model.objVal))\n",
    "for t in range(periods):\n",
    "   print(\"Period {}: setup = {}, lotsize = {}, inventory = {}\".format(\n",
    "         t, setup[t].x, lotsize[t].x, inventory[t].x\n",
    "      ))\n",
    "cost = 0\n",
    "inv = initial_forecast\n",
    "for t in range(periods):\n",
    "   if setup[t].x > 0:\n",
    "      cost = cost + setup_cost\n",
    "   inv = alpha * realised_demands[t] + (1 - alpha) * inv\n",
    "   inv = inv + lotsize[t].x - realised_demands[t] - safety_stock\n",
    "   if inv > 0:\n",
    "      cost += holding_cost * inv\n",
    "   else:\n",
    "      cost += backorder_cost * abs(inv)\n",
    "\n",
    "print(\"Cost: {}\".format(cost))\n"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 3,
   "id": "362833ca",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Gurobi Optimizer version 10.0.1 build v10.0.1rc0 (win64)\n",
      "\n",
      "CPU model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]\n",
      "Thread count: 6 physical cores, 12 logical processors, using up to 12 threads\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimize a model with 606 rows, 35 columns and 1130 nonzeros\n",
      "Model fingerprint: 0x8b51ed37\n",
      "Variable types: 30 continuous, 5 integer (5 binary)\n",
      "Coefficient statistics:\n",
      "  Matrix range     [1e+00, 3e+01]\n",
      "  Objective range  [1e+02, 8e+03]\n",
      "  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]\n",
      "  RHS range        [7e-01, 3e+01]\n",
      "Presolve removed 10 rows and 0 columns\n",
      "Presolve time: 0.00s\n",
      "\n",
      "Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.02 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "Thread count was 1 (of 12 available processors)\n",
      "\n",
      "Solution count 0\n",
      "\n",
      "Model is infeasible\n",
      "Best objective -, best bound -, gap -\n"
     ]
    },
    {
     "ename": "AttributeError",
     "evalue": "Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'",
     "output_type": "error",
     "traceback": [
      "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;31mAttributeError\u001b[0m                            Traceback (most recent call last)",
      "Cell \u001b[1;32mIn[3], line 41\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m     38\u001b[0m m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39moptimize()\n\u001b[0;32m     40\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;66;03m# Print the optimal objective value and variable values\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m---> 41\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28mprint\u001b[39m(\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mOptimal value:\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m, \u001b[43mm\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mgetObjective\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mgetValue\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m)\n\u001b[0;32m     42\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mfor\u001b[39;00m v \u001b[38;5;129;01min\u001b[39;00m m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mgetVars():\n\u001b[0;32m     43\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mif\u001b[39;00m v\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mx \u001b[38;5;241m>\u001b[39m \u001b[38;5;241m0\u001b[39m:\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\linexpr.pxi:396\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.LinExpr.getValue\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\var.pxi:125\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.Var.__getattr__\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\var.pxi:153\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.Var.getAttr\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\attrutil.pxi:100\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.__getattr\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;31mAttributeError\u001b[0m: Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "#5) Scenarios = 20\n",
    "import gurobipy as gp\n",
    "from gurobipy import *\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import random\n",
    "from scipy.stats import norm\n",
    "\n",
    "locations = 5\n",
    "customers = 6\n",
    "scenarios = 20\n",
    "\n",
    "capacity = [18,24,27,22,31,0]\n",
    "mean = [10,8,14,6,7,11]\n",
    "std_dev = [mean[i]/2 for i in range(customers)]\n",
    "cost = [[1675,400,685,1630,1160,2800],[1460,1940,970,100,495,1200],[1925,2400,1425,500,950,800],[380,1355,543,1045,665,2321],[922,1646,700,508,311,1797],[3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000]]\n",
    "fixed = [7650,3500,5000,4100,2200]\n",
    "\n",
    "# Define the model\n",
    "m = gp.Model('Stochastic Warehouse Location Problem')\n",
    "\n",
    "# Define the decision variables\n",
    "x = m.addVars(locations, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='x')\n",
    "y = m.addVars(locations, customers, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='y')\n",
    "\n",
    "# Define the objective function\n",
    "obj = quicksum(fixed[i]*x[i] for i in range(locations)) + quicksum(cost[i][j]*y[i,j] for i in range(locations) for j in range(customers))\n",
    "m.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)\n",
    "\n",
    "# Add capacity constraints\n",
    "m.addConstrs((quicksum(y[i,j] for i in range(locations)) <= capacity[j] for j in range(customers)), name='Capacity')\n",
    "\n",
    "# Add customer demand constraints for each scenario\n",
    "for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "    d = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev)  # sample demand scenario\n",
    "    m.addConstrs((y[i,j] >= d[j] - x[i]*capacity[j] for i in range(locations) for j in range(customers)), name='Demand')\n",
    "\n",
    "# Solve the model\n",
    "m.optimize()\n",
    "\n",
    "# Print the optimal objective value and variable values\n",
    "print(\"Optimal value:\", m.getObjective().getValue())\n",
    "for v in m.getVars():\n",
    "    if v.x > 0:\n",
    "        print(v.varName, v.x)\n"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 4,
   "id": "fa753ac2",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "Gurobi Optimizer version 10.0.1 build v10.0.1rc0 (win64)\n",
      "\n",
      "CPU model: AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]\n",
      "Thread count: 6 physical cores, 12 logical processors, using up to 12 threads\n",
      "\n",
      "Optimize a model with 605 rows, 35 columns and 3035 nonzeros\n",
      "Model fingerprint: 0x318eb7cb\n",
      "Variable types: 0 continuous, 35 integer (35 binary)\n",
      "Coefficient statistics:\n",
      "  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+03]\n",
      "  Objective range  [2e+03, 4e+06]\n",
      "  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]\n",
      "  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+00]\n",
      "Presolve time: 0.01s\n",
      "\n",
      "Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.04 seconds (0.00 work units)\n",
      "Thread count was 1 (of 12 available processors)\n",
      "\n",
      "Solution count 0\n",
      "\n",
      "Model is infeasible\n",
      "Best objective -, best bound -, gap -\n"
     ]
    },
    {
     "ename": "AttributeError",
     "evalue": "Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'",
     "output_type": "error",
     "traceback": [
      "\u001b[1;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------\u001b[0m",
      "\u001b[1;31mAttributeError\u001b[0m                            Traceback (most recent call last)",
      "Cell \u001b[1;32mIn[4], line 65\u001b[0m\n\u001b[0;32m     62\u001b[0m m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39moptimize()\n\u001b[0;32m     64\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;66;03m# Print the optimal objective value and variable values\u001b[39;00m\n\u001b[1;32m---> 65\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28mprint\u001b[39m(\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mOptimal value:\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m\"\u001b[39m, \u001b[43mm\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mgetObjective\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m\u001b[38;5;241;43m.\u001b[39;49m\u001b[43mgetValue\u001b[49m\u001b[43m(\u001b[49m\u001b[43m)\u001b[49m)\n\u001b[0;32m     66\u001b[0m \u001b[38;5;28;01mfor\u001b[39;00m v \u001b[38;5;129;01min\u001b[39;00m m\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mgetVars():\n\u001b[0;32m     67\u001b[0m     \u001b[38;5;28;01mif\u001b[39;00m v\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mvarName[\u001b[38;5;241m0\u001b[39m] \u001b[38;5;241m==\u001b[39m \u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124mx\u001b[39m\u001b[38;5;124m'\u001b[39m \u001b[38;5;129;01mand\u001b[39;00m v\u001b[38;5;241m.\u001b[39mx \u001b[38;5;241m>\u001b[39m \u001b[38;5;241m0\u001b[39m:\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\linexpr.pxi:396\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.LinExpr.getValue\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\var.pxi:125\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.Var.__getattr__\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\var.pxi:153\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.Var.getAttr\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "File \u001b[1;32msrc\\gurobipy\\attrutil.pxi:100\u001b[0m, in \u001b[0;36mgurobipy.__getattr\u001b[1;34m()\u001b[0m\n",
      "\u001b[1;31mAttributeError\u001b[0m: Unable to retrieve attribute 'x'"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "#5) Scenarios = 100\n",
    "import gurobipy as gp\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import math\n",
    "\n",
    "# Define problem data\n",
    "locations = 5\n",
    "customers = 6\n",
    "scenarios = 100\n",
    "\n",
    "capacity = [18,24,27,22,31]\n",
    "mean = [10,8,14,6,7,11]\n",
    "std_dev = [x/2 for x in mean]  # Half of the mean for each market as the standard deviation\n",
    "cost = [[1675,400,685,1630,1160,2800],\n",
    "        [1460,1940,970,100,495,1200],\n",
    "        [1925,2400,1425,500,950,800],\n",
    "        [380,1355,543,1045,665,2321],\n",
    "        [922,1646,700,508,311,1797],\n",
    "        [3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000]]\n",
    "fixed = [7650,3500,5000,4100,2200]\n",
    "\n",
    "# Generate scenarios for demand using normal distribution\n",
    "np.random.seed(1)  # Set the seed to get consistent results\n",
    "demand = np.zeros((scenarios, customers))\n",
    "for i in range(customers):\n",
    "    demand[:,i] = np.random.normal(mean[i], std_dev[i], scenarios)\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create optimization model\n",
    "m = gp.Model()\n",
    "\n",
    "# Create variables\n",
    "x = m.addVars(locations, customers, vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name=\"x\")\n",
    "y = m.addVars(locations, vtype=gp.GRB.BINARY, name=\"y\")\n",
    "\n",
    "# Set objective function\n",
    "obj = gp.LinExpr()\n",
    "for j in range(customers):\n",
    "    for i in range(locations):\n",
    "        for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "            obj += demand[s,j] * cost[j][i] * x[i,j]\n",
    "for i in range(locations):\n",
    "    obj += fixed[i] * y[i]\n",
    "m.setObjective(obj, gp.GRB.MINIMIZE)\n",
    "\n",
    "# Add capacity constraints\n",
    "for i in range(locations):\n",
    "    lhs = gp.LinExpr()\n",
    "    for j in range(customers):\n",
    "        for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "            lhs += demand[s,j] * x[i,j]\n",
    "    m.addConstr(lhs <= capacity[i] * y[i], name=\"capacity_constr{}\".format(i))\n",
    "\n",
    "# Add demand constraints\n",
    "for j in range(customers):\n",
    "    for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "        lhs = gp.LinExpr()\n",
    "        for i in range(locations):\n",
    "            lhs += x[i,j]\n",
    "        m.addConstr(lhs == 1, name=\"demand_constr{}_{}\".format(j, s))\n",
    "\n",
    "# Solve the model\n",
    "m.optimize()\n",
    "\n",
    "# Print the optimal objective value and variable values\n",
    "print(\"Optimal value:\", m.getObjective().getValue())\n",
    "for v in m.getVars():\n",
    "    if v.varName[0] == 'x' and v.x > 0:\n",
    "        print(v.varName, v.x)\n"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 5,
   "id": "c7b2b261",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [
    {
     "name": "stdout",
     "output_type": "stream",
     "text": [
      "[[ 7.  6. 12. 12. 12.  7.  5.  2.  4.  6. 10.  1. 15. 16.  8.  2. 10. 12.\n",
      "  13. 15. 15. 15. 17. 15.  9.  8. 17. 15. 13. 13. 11. 14.  6. 16.  7. 11.\n",
      "   7.  9.  7.  9.  8.  4. 11.  8. 11.  6. 15. 19.  4.  9. 12. 12.  9.  4.\n",
      "   3.  5. 11. 12.  5. 13.  5.  5. 10.  7. 15.  4.  7. 16.  8.  8. 12. 12.\n",
      "  17.  2.  8. 15.  6.  2. 10.  8. 13.  3. 24.  7.  8. 15.  9.  5. 11.  8.\n",
      "  17.  0. 11. 12.  8.  9. 13.  6.  5. 11.]\n",
      " [13.  5.  5.  5. 11. 14. 11.  0.  7.  5. 10. 10. 14.  3.  6. 11.  8.  6.\n",
      "  10.  7.  9.  9.  6.  0.  8.  7.  7. 14.  7.  7.  3. 11. 12. 10.  7. 12.\n",
      "  15.  7.  6.  7.  2.  6.  5.  2.  6.  7.  9.  9.  5. 13.  8.  5.  2.  5.\n",
      "  13.  5. 10.  7.  3.  2.  8.  5.  7.  7.  6.  3.  1.  8.  3. 10.  4.  5.\n",
      "  15.  5.  8.  9.  5.  7.  0.  4.  6.  7. 11.  4. 13. 16.  9.  9. 18.  9.\n",
      "  11. 14. 11. 15.  8. 10.  9. 15. 11.  1.]\n",
      " [22. 12. 14.  9. 26. 14. 29.  6.  9. 12.  9. 12.  6.  9. 27.  4. 17.  7.\n",
      "  12. 16. 26. 21. 22.  6. 16. 20. 22. 19. 18. 18.  9. 21. 14. 30. 20.  4.\n",
      "   9. 12. 10. 15. 11. 13. 19. 13. 11. 15. 22. 19. 19. 14. 10. 18. 16. 15.\n",
      "   1. 22. 13. 19.  8. 19. 19. 14. 21. 23.  6. 20.  5. 10. 20. 16.  7. 17.\n",
      "  12. 25. 20. 26. 17. 30. 23. 16.  4. 12. 22. 16. 16. 19. 25. 22. 12. 11.\n",
      "   9. 19. 11. 23. 18. 11. 13. 22. 14.  4.]\n",
      " [ 7.  1.  7.  9.  7.  6.  2.  2.  6.  9.  5.  4.  6.  9.  8. 11.  9.  6.\n",
      "   5. 13.  3. 13.  6.  4.  4.  3.  9.  6.  6.  9.  1.  3.  7.  6. 11.  8.\n",
      "   8.  2. 10.  5.  6. 10.  2.  1.  7.  9.  7.  7.  3.  6.  4.  9.  7.  5.\n",
      "   7.  2.  9.  7. 10. 10.  9. 10.  7. 10.  9.  7.  7. 10.  6. 13.  7.  0.\n",
      "   4.  6.  7.  7.  7.  8.  6.  8.  8.  8. 11.  6.  6. 17.  6.  5.  7.  0.\n",
      "   7.  4.  5.  3.  7.  3.  4.  8.  5.  4.]\n",
      " [ 1.  6.  9. 11.  6.  7.  1.  6.  8.  4.  5.  4.  2.  6. 10.  4.  9.  1.\n",
      "   5.  9.  6.  0. 14.  5.  8.  8. 11.  7.  2.  4.  4.  2.  8.  8.  6. 13.\n",
      "   9.  5.  4.  8.  6.  5.  5. 11.  7. 11.  7.  2.  6. 10.  3.  6. 10.  8.\n",
      "  11.  1.  6.  3.  9.  2.  2.  3.  8.  4. 10.  1.  1. 13. 12.  0.  6.  6.\n",
      "   5.  7.  8. 10.  9.  7.  9.  5.  0.  6.  0. 11.  7.  5.  8. 11.  7.  5.\n",
      "   5.  2.  8.  8.  3. 10.  7.  7.  2. 10.]\n",
      " [ 7. 11.  8. 16. 14.  1.  7. 16. 14.  8.  4. 14. 10. 15.  2.  8.  7.  6.\n",
      "  12. 17.  9.  9. 11. 18. 18.  5.  6. 20.  9.  7. 10. 12. 18. 15. 14.  1.\n",
      "  17. 11.  5. 13. 10. 13.  9. 17.  4. 15.  5. 19.  7. 22.  3.  7.  8. 10.\n",
      "   7. 22.  0. 13. 11.  6. 13.  7. 14.  7. 16.  5.  7.  7. 19. 25. 16. 16.\n",
      "  14.  7.  7. 15. 15.  9. 12. 11.  5. 10. 12. 15.  7. 12. 16. 11. 14.  4.\n",
      "  11.  9. 16. 14. 14. 11. 17.  5. 14. 10.]]\n",
      "48890.100000000006\n",
      "{0: <gurobi.Var C1 (value 1.0)>, 1: <gurobi.Var C2 (value 0.0)>, 2: <gurobi.Var C3 (value 1.0)>, 3: <gurobi.Var C4 (value 1.0)>, 4: <gurobi.Var C5 (value 0.9999999999999956)>}\n"
     ]
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "#5) benders decom\n",
    "import gurobipy as gp\n",
    "from gurobipy import *\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import random\n",
    "from scipy.stats import norm\n",
    "\n",
    "locations = 5\n",
    "customers = 6\n",
    "scenarios = 100\n",
    "\n",
    "capacity = [18,24,27,22,31]\n",
    "mean = [10,8,14,6,7,11]\n",
    "cost = [[1675,400,685,1630,1160,2800],[1460,1940,970,100,495,1200],[1925,2400,1425,500,950,800],[380,1355,543,1045,665,2321],[922,1646,700,508,311,1797],[3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000]]\n",
    "fixed = [7650,3500,5000,4100,2200]\n",
    "\n",
    "demand = np.zeros((customers,scenarios))\n",
    "for j in range(customers):\n",
    "    for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "        demand[j,s]=max(0,round(mean[j]+norm.ppf(random.random())*0.5*mean[j]))\n",
    "print(demand)\n",
    "\n",
    "# Define Benders subproblem\n",
    "        \n",
    "def subproblem(model, where):\n",
    "    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:\n",
    "        v_y = model.cbGetSolution(model._y)\n",
    "        LB = model.cbGetSolution(model._z)\n",
    "        objective = 0\n",
    "        coeff_v = 0\n",
    "        coeff_w=np.zeros(locations)\n",
    "        for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "          bsp = gp.Model(\"Subproblem\") \n",
    "          bsp.setParam('LogToConsole', 0)\n",
    "          x = {}\n",
    "          for i in range(locations+1):\n",
    "            for j in range(customers):\n",
    "               x[i,j] = bsp.addVar(obj=cost[i][j]/scenarios)\n",
    "          for j in range(customers):\n",
    "             bsp.addConstr(sum(x[i,j] for i in range(locations+1)) >= demand[j,s],name=\"v\"+str(j))\n",
    "          for i in range(locations):\n",
    "             bsp.addConstr(sum(x[i,j] for j in range(customers)) <= capacity[i]*v_y[i],name=\"u\"+str(i)) \n",
    "          bsp.optimize()\n",
    "          objective = objective+bsp.objVal\n",
    "          coeff_v = coeff_v+sum(demand[j,s]*bsp.getConstrByName(\"v\"+str(j)).pi for j in range(customers))\n",
    "          for i in range(locations):\n",
    "            coeff_w[i] = coeff_w[i]+capacity[i]*bsp.getConstrByName(\"u\"+str(i)).pi\n",
    "          bsp.dispose\n",
    "        if objective > LB:\n",
    "          model.cbLazy(model._z >= coeff_v+sum(coeff_w[i]*model._y[i] for i in range(locations)))\n",
    "        \n",
    "                       \n",
    "# Masterproblem\n",
    "                     \n",
    "m = gp.Model(\"Benders Masterproblem\")\n",
    "\n",
    "y = {}\n",
    "z = m.addVar(obj=1)                                                                           \n",
    "for i in range(locations):\n",
    "  y[i] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,obj=fixed[i])\n",
    "for s in range(scenarios):\n",
    "  m.addConstr(sum(capacity[i]*y[i] for i in range(locations)) >= sum(demand[j,s] for j in range(customers)))\n",
    "m.setParam('LogToConsole', 0)\n",
    "m.Params.lazyConstraints = 1\n",
    "m._y = y\n",
    "m._z = z\n",
    "m.optimize(subproblem)\n",
    "\n",
    "print(m.objVal)\n",
    "print(m._y)\n"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "id": "1f144935",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.10.9"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5
}
```

This code have come error help me fix that code
this code 619 to 623 have error help
The code first defines the problem parameters, such as the number of items, the demand for each item, the setup cost, the holding cost, and the order cost. The code then creates variables for the order quantities and replenishment periods. The code then defines the objective function, which is to minimize the total cost of ordering and holding inventory. The code then adds constraints to the model